# How can I combine semantic versions?

Tags: semantic-versioning

I have a product that ships in two formats: individual packages and a combined single package. The single package is programmatically generated from the individual packages. The individual package semantic versions are manually determined and set.

How can I calculate a semantic version for the single package based on the semantic versions of each individual packages that respects the semantic versioning rules of the individual packages?

For discussion purposes, assume I have three individual packages:

```
a - 1.0.3
b - 2.1.0
c - 1.1.1
```

How would I calculate the single package's version?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create a unique version for each combination of three, the simplest way is to explicitly show each component:

```
a - 1.0.3
b - 2.1.0
c - 1.1.1

mainprog-a1.0.3-b2.1.0-c1.1.1
```

This helps you identify each individual component that make up the whole. That's a bit long, so alternative you could hash that:

```
sha256(a1.0.3-b2.1.0-c1.1.1)[1..10] = 6b5da1e87f
```

You'd want to store a table of each sum to the base components that made it, so you can easily look up the components. Either that or you could find a reversible hash algorithm to use instead.

You could of course just sum the numbers like in the other answer:

```
a - 1.0.3
b - 2.1.0
c - 1.1.1

result - (1+2+1).(0+1+1).(3+0+1)
result - 4.2.4
```

But here, it's ambiguous which three components made 4.2.4. You'd have to come up with some convoluted math formula to ensure individual versions would always add up to a 1-to-1 mapping to the final package version.

Answer (score 0):

The numbers would become quite large, but one solution is to sum the individual components:

```
a - 1.0.3
b - 2.1.0
c - 1.1.1

result - (1+2+1).(0+1+1).(3+0+1)
result - 4.2.4
```